# How to conditionally align web text?

Tags: jquery, css, line, text-alignment

Given a fairly short string of `H1`-styled text, I would like to conditionally set the `text alignment` property based on whether the text spans beyond a single line.

If the string only takes up a single line, I want to set the property to `center`.

Otherwise (given the string, it shouldn't ever take more than two lines), I'd like the first line aligned left; the second, right. To force the string to wrap where I want, I used non-breaking spaces for all but one space--which means I can use `.split(' ')` to target the different substrings.

I'm already using jQuery 1.9.1 in this project so that's available solution in addition to CSS.

Answer (score 0):

First set `h1 { text-align: center; }` in your css, then you can test if the the width of the `h1` is greater than some value, and then edit the css based on that:

```
$('h1').each(function(){
    var width = $(this).css('width').replace(/(?:[.](?=.*[.])|[^\d.])+/g, "");
    if (width > yourValue) {
        $('h1').css('text-align', 'left')
    }
});
```

I have no idea how to make the second line `text-align: right;`, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try calculating the height and running an if statement...

```
var oneLineOfText = $('h1').height(),
    theH1 = $('h1')
    numOfChars = 20; //find out how many chars fit on one line

if ( oneLineOfText <= theH1.height() )
   {
        theH1.css('text-align', 'center');
   }
else
   {
        var line1 = theH1.html().substring(0,numOfChars),
            line2 = theH1.html().substring(numOfChars);
        line1.css('text-align','left');
        line2.css('text-align', 'right');
   }
```

Not tested, but I think that should get you close...

Comment: I like your check against the element height but I'm having trouble splitting the string: `var lines = $('h1').text().split(' '); lines[0].css('text-align', 'left'), lines[1].css('text-align', 'right');` isn't getting me anywhere.

Comment: I don't think I'd use split unless you know the exact character that you'd want to split the line on.  The substring I listed above will split the line on a certain number. So what I would do is to find out the number of characters that will safely fit on one line and assign it to numOfChars. Then run that check and split it out accordingly. Perhaps you could wrap each line in a span with a class so the javascript doesn't assign the CSS.

Comment: I do know the exact character: There's only one breaking space (' ') in the string. The rest are non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`).